# btoa javascript e base64_decode php

Tags: php, javascript, codificação-de-caracteres

Estou passando uma string em javascript/jQuery utilizando btoa(), o código está assim:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button#btnGravarDados").on('click', function(){
    var codigoDadosPessoais = $("#codigoDadosPessoais").val();
    var dataDadosPessoais = $("#dataDadosPessoais").val();
    var documentoDadosPessoais = $("#documentoDadosPessoais").val();
    var documento2DadosPessoais = $("#documento2DadosPessoais").val();
    var nomeDadosPessoais = $("#nomeDadosPessoais").val();
    var cepDadosPessoais = $("#cepDadosPessoais").val();
    var enderecoDadosPessoais = $("#enderecoDadosPessoais").val();
    var numeroDadosPessoais = $("#numeroDadosPessoais").val();
    var complementoDadosPessoais = $("#complementoDadosPessoais").val();
    var bairroDadosPessoais = $("#bairroDadosPessoais").val();
    var cidadeDadosPessoais = $("#cidadeDadosPessoais").val();
    var ufDadosPessoais = $("#ufDadosPessoais").val();
    var observacoesDadosPessoais = $("#observacoesDadosPessoais").val();

    var transfere = codigoDadosPessoais + "_" + dataDadosPessoais + "_" + documentoDadosPessoais + "_" +  documento2DadosPessoais + "_" + nomeDadosPessoais + "_" + cepDadosPessoais + "_" + enderecoDadosPessoais + "_" + numeroDadosPessoais + "_" + complementoDadosPessoais + "_" + bairroDadosPessoais + "_" + cidadeDadosPessoais + "_" + ufDadosPessoais + "_" + observacoesDadosPessoais;

    $('#returnDados').load('cliente-cadastro.php?valor=' + btoa(transfere) + '');

  });
});
</script>
```

No arquivo cliente-cadastro.php está assim:

```
<?php
$valor = $_REQUEST['valor'];
$valor = base64_decode($valor);
$explode = explode("_", $valor);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($explode);
echo "</pre>";
?>
```

Porém o print_r retorna:

```
Array
(
   [0] => 
)
```

Fiz depois de:

```
$valor = $_REQUEST['valor'];
echo $valor;
```

E imprime a cadeia ASCII codificada base-64, então ela (variável $valor) está recebendo a string, mas fazendo uso do echo base64_decode($valor); já não exibe nada.

Comment: Passando pela url? Não seria melhor fazer via `POST`?

Comment: Tente isto `valor=' + escape(btoa(transfere))`

Comment: Guilherme Nascimento, funcionou agora. Obrigado!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fiz uma [simulação](https://www.ideone.com/WJw3Y8) semelhante a seu código PHP e ele funcionou corretamente.

O que pode estar afetando resultado é o valor que você recebe no `request`, veja se não existe nenhum caractere especial.

Você pode utilizar a função [encodeURI()](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURI) do `javascript` para evitar problemas com esses caracteres:

```
var transfere = codigoDadosPessoais + "_" + dataDadosPessoais + "_" + documentoDadosPessoais + "_" +  documento2DadosPessoais + "_" + nomeDadosPessoais + "_" + cepDadosPessoais + "_" + enderecoDadosPessoais + "_" + numeroDadosPessoais + "_" + complementoDadosPessoais + "_" + bairroDadosPessoais + "_" + cidadeDadosPessoais + "_" + ufDadosPessoais + "_" + observacoesDadosPessoais;
var url = 'cliente-cadastro.php?valor=' + encodeURI(btoa(transfere)) + '';
$('#returnDados').load(url);
```

Comment: 'Reforcei' o código e de fato já havia feito uso do encodeURI a um tempo atrás, mas não me recordava, obrigado por isso.